# Rewriting image names during page display

Tags: php, image, seo, url-rewriting

I've a web site where i have many listings. Lets say products. All products have slugs generated by the name of the products and stored in database. And all products have images under the folder of /images/products/

I use php, no framework.

At the moment i give name to images with using the slug during upload process.

Example: 
Product Id: 2500
Product Name: Plazma TV 
URL Slug: plazma-tv 
Image Name: plazma-tv-01.jpg (and goes on -02.jpg -03.jpg ...)

What i want to do is to upload all the images with product ids (2500-01.jpg...)
And change the image names to slug-01.jpg when page is displayed by visitor.

Reason to change the name is to be able to use the image name and alt text for a better seo success in search results.

I've more than 60.000 photos uploded at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you want better server organization but also seo friendly names, in which case i would keep the images with `{slug}-{number}` format, but organize them into folders via id: `/images/products/{id}/{slug}-{number}.jpg`

Comment: This is what i'm planing to do at the moment but i wanted to know if there is a chance to store images with id names. Sometimes i need to change the product name (also slug) and i don't want to update the image names all the time when slug is changed

Comment: Yes in theory you could have php handle all img requests, parse the name from the requested url, lookup the ID in the database, and find the appropriate image. But that is likely to be slow and put a lot of strain on the server. Instead write a simple script to hand image renaming on product name change - then the load is encounter once during change, vs everytime an image is requested

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'll go with renaming the images on slug change.